# Get rails variables as parameter to an onclick event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, onclick

I'm trying to do something: I have a event listener to call a function when a button is clicked (there is a dynamic amount of them), but I would like to pass an additionnal argument to the function depending, which would be a parameter defined in my controller.

Do you have any clue about how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is set a data-* field in your html with the value from this "variable" set in the controller and inside the javascript function, get this.

For example, an .html.erb

```
<button id="my_id" data-myvalue="<%= $my_value %>">click me</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("my_id").onclick = function() {
console.log(this.getAttribute("data-myvalue"));
}
```

Comment: Further to this, you must remember that Rails is a back-end infrastructure, meaning you can only "call" Rails data on your front-end if you explicitly set it at render time. 

To do this, you need to make sure you can set the Rails-centric data in your controller backend, to render in the view (IE - you cannot just "pass" Rails data to your browser -- it *has* to go through the view / HTML)

To do this, you basically need to output the Rails data (from Chris' example the `data` attributes) to make sure your HTML view can output the required information